# How to insert additional words or marks above a certain text and between lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to insert additional words or marks above a certain text and between lines as in the example below (k1, k2, k3).

Some similar questions suggest TikZ would solve this. But I am not familiar with TikZ at all. Your help is needed.

[image]

Comment: Dear Junqi, this could indeed be achieved with TikZ, but perhaps also with other means. Am I right with my guess that the words or marks shall sit above or after a certain character within a word? Or should they be centered above a whole word? Further, could you perhaps tell us the structure of these marks? Is it always a small line or hook and then a K with a superscript number? Or could it also be something completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With TikZ, you could maybe do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mk}[3]{%
 \edef\hook{V}\edef\attr{#1}%
 \tikz[overlay]{% 
 \ifx\hook\attr%
  \draw (0,1em) -- (0,{1em-3pt}) ; %
 \else%
  \draw[line join=bevel] (0,1em) -- (.75pt,{1em-3pt}) -- (1.5pt,1em) ; %
 \fi%
 \node[anchor=west, inner sep=0] at (2pt,1.1em) { \tiny #2\textsuperscript{#3}}; }%
}

\begin{document}

vij\={a}ti\mk{I}{K}{1}vyav\d{r}tta\d{m} b\={a}hya\mk{V}{K}{2}m

\end{document}
```

[image]

Beware: This solution uses overlays. You should increase the line skip in order to avoid overlaps.